# How to extend templates in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, layout

1. I have a web site in which all pages shares a common header and a footer. There are some controller actions use this layout as the template
2. There is also another template which is a tabbed one. After signing in to the application users will get a tabbed interface (which also has the same header and footer). I have this application written in **Stripes** framework (Java Based). In that, there is a main template (which contains header and footer) which gets extended to a tabbed interface (This one another template) and then all other actions adds something specific (Actual page which will gets displayed) to that template and result gets displayed.

Suppose there is a profile page, account page which is using the tabbed interface (which is using the 2nd template) and an about us page, contact us page using the first template.

In zend as I know if I want all the capability of the first template in the second template I have to copy all of that template to this template. Isn't that so? or is there is any extending capability available here ? After extending can I use that template for the account and profile pages directly instead of the first one ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,

In your Layout folder you can have folder called 'parts' and in their you can have header and footer separately, and in you main template page, you can call them as below,

```
<head>  
  <title>Site Title</title>
</head> 
<body>
  <?php echo $this->render('parts/header.phtml') ?>
  <?php echo $this->layout()->content ?>
  <?php echo $this->render('parts/footer.phtml') ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can have all the common elements in one template, and other ares can be loaded in to that template dynamically as of your requirement.

Comment: That means I have to repeat code for a menu system and some other components needed, in the accounts and profile page. Or can I have another common template which contains all these functionalities, so that in future if I have to change something I don't have to repeat all those things in the accounts and profile pages. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: No actually you would use [view helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html) to provide the functionality each page type requires. If you use the view tools provided your code can be very DRY. You can add/remove view helpers as needed using controller plugins or just in the init() or preDispatch() methods of the controller.